# Update table A with all new entries from table B AND update existing entries in A via B

Tags: mysql

I have a table A that contains a few columns with entries. In column 1 is an unique campaign name. Table A contains all relevant historical data.
I have another table B that contains the same columns with entries, too. Some of the entries that are in table B can also already exist in table A (campaign name is equal with table A) but can (not must) contain diffent entries in the other columns. B is my update table with (some) new data.

Now that what I want to do:
I want add all new entries (rows where campaign name in Column 1 is not already in the table) completely from table B to A and update/replace the existing entries (rows where campaign name in column 1 is already in A) with the diffent entries in the other columns.

Here´s an example:

For example if the table A contained:

```
|col1                           ||col2   ||col3|
+-----+
|20161512_NL_Luxus_1_DE         ||Andrea ||29 |
|20161217_LC_YoBirthdayNo_A_CH  ||Oscar  ||38 |
|20161512_NL_SDT_4_DE           ||James  ||44 |
|20170117_SV_YoBirthdayYes_A_DE ||Julia  ||57 |
```

And table B contained:

```
|col1                           ||col2   ||col3|
+------+
|20161512_NL_SDT_4_DE           ||James  ||44 |
|20170117_SV_YoBirthdayYes_A_DE ||George ||12 | 
|20161230_LC_YoBirthdayNo_A_CH  ||Hank   ||97 | 
|20170101_SV_YoBirthdayYes_A_DE ||Selma  ||77 |
```

I want a query that will update Table A as following:

```
|col1                           ||col2   ||col3|
+-----+
|20161512_NL_Luxus_1_DE         ||Andrea ||29 |
|20161217_LC_YoBirthdayNo_A_CH  ||Oscar  ||38 |
|20161512_NL_SDT_4_DE           ||James  ||44 |
|20170117_SV_YoBirthdayYes_A_DE ||George ||12 | 
|20161230_LC_YoBirthdayNo_A_CH  ||Hank   ||97 | 
|20170101_SV_YoBirthdayYes_A_DE ||Selma  ||77 |
```

That's what I've got so far:

```
INSERT INTO A SELECT * FROM B WHERE `col1` NOT IN (SELECT `col1` FROM `A`);
```

-> But that´s only one part of the solution...

Unfortunately I have no idea how to solve this problem... :/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually '20161512' is twice in Your expected result right?

Comment: I think you need to insert value from table B to table A.

Comment: Yes: but `20161512` is not the complete campaign name - it´s only the first part of it (`20161512_NL_Luxus_1_DE` and `20161512_NL_SDT_4_DE` are the complete campaign names) : `|20161512_NL_Luxus_1_DE ||Andrea ||29 |` & `|20161512_NL_SDT_4_DE ||James ||44 |` should both be in my result but only once each

Comment: Maybe I found the answer one my own... will this work? `UPDATE A 
INNER JOIN B ON A.col1 = B.col1 SET A.col2 =B.col2, A.col3 =B.col3;` (and so on) Then `INSERT INTO A SELECT * FROM B WHERE col1 NOT IN (SELECT col1 FROM `A);`

Comment: I know - that would be not the most elegant way...but will it work?!

Comment: Yes it should work

Comment: See INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY...

Answer (score 0):

If `col1` is `primary key` you can try this:

```
    INSERT INTO A 
    SELECT * FROM B ON DUPLICATE KEY
    UPDATE col2=VALUES(col2), col3=VALUES(col3);
```